# Creating new files from an old one

Tags: php

```
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
 //look for the first payor block
if(strpos($line, 'N1*PR*') !== false || $block_start) {
 $header_end = true; $block_start = true;
  //see if the block finished
if(strpos($line, 'CAS*CO*45*20.43**253*1.27~') !== false) {
$block_start = false;
 $payor_blocks[$count] .= $line;
 $count++;
 }
  $payor_blocks[$count] .= $line;
  } else {
  //append to the header
  if($header_end) {
   $footer .= $line."\n";
 } else {
 $header .= $line."\n";
 }
  }
 }

 //get payor blocks and create a file foreach payor
 $new_files = array();
 foreach($payor_blocks as $block) {
$filename = $file . "_" . $count;
 $count++;
$new_files[] = array(
 'name' => $filename,
 'content' => $header."\n".$block."\n".$footer  

  );

 //loop through new files and create them
    foreach($new_files as $new_file) {
    $myfile = fopen($file, "x");
    fwrite($myfile, $new_file['content']);  
    //close the file
    fclose($myfile);
```

I have the code above, it's suppose to be able to open an original file called `"$file"` and create a new file then close it, However its not creating and when I run it, i get this warning error:

```
  Warning: fopen(362931550.1a): failed to open stream: 
File exists in /script2.php on line 90 Warning: 
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
 boolean given in /script2.php on line 94 Warning: 
fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean 
given in /script2.php on line 96
```

Any help is kindly appreciated.

I have one file named: `362931550.1a`
I did a code that splits them at certain areas, (its pretty long to post), when i run the script I see it on my browser but it doesn't create 2 new files in the folder.

Comment: Read that with `x` mode - `If the file already exists, the fopen() call will fail by returning FALSE and generating an error of level E_WARNING.`

Comment: I tried to put w however i didnt get the output i wanted., any ideas what else I could put? @u_mulder

Comment: We don't know what output you want and what you get so please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: Done check it out @u_mulder

Comment: Without more context we can't know for sure what's happening, but you're opening `$file` for writing, not `$new_file`. Unless you change the value of `$file` in your loop somehow you're just opening and writing to the same file over and over…

Comment: I added the codes that have to do with the foreach, like I said the code it really long if I post it all. However, "file" is the name of the original file. @Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file open mode is incorrect.

From [php.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> 'x'   Create and open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file. If the file already exists, the fopen() call will fail by returning FALSE and generating an error of level E_WARNING [...]

You should probably use 'w' mode:

> 'w'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Comment: What can I put instead of x that gives me the output that I want?

Comment: I tried that it just puts one file instead the old, it doesn't create 2 new ones.

Comment: There is no code in your sample to create two files. Please clarify your problem in question.

Comment: I posted the code that has to do with it, and as I mentioned, my code is really long, it'll be very vague if I post it all.

Answer (score 0):

The script failed to open a stream with the `fopen()` function and return a boolean. The function `fwrite()` become the boolean value but need a resource.

The reason is that you only create files with the x-modifier in the stream.

> Create and open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file. If the file already exists, the fopen() call will fail by returning FALSE and generating an error of level E_WARNING. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

You see in the PHP manual more informations about the stream-modes ([PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)).

To prevent this message check if the value isn't false.

```
$stream = fopen("file.txt", "x");
if($stream === false) {
    echo "Error while open stream";
}

//here your code
```